# How do I replay levels?

Tags: jet-set-radio

Every mission/level has a leaderboard score, but I can't find an obvious way to replay levels to attempt a higher ranking, even from the score menu in Settings. How can I replay specific story levels? Do I have to make a new game and play through again?

Comment: I don't really remember - have you finished everything yet? You may be able to play any section after completing it all.

Comment: @Samthere Once you beat the game, you get access to three "free roam" missions that let you visit nearly every area in the game, but it won't let you replay individual missions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can't return to specific story levels.

To return to a previous level, you'll have to play through the story again. When you finish the game, you can reuse your save for your next playthrough.

Another option: turn off autosave and you can replay the same level by hard-resetting the game after each run.

Comment: This only applies to the Dreamcast original. The Steam version was updated with a replay option

Answer (score 2):

**The Steam version of Jet Set Radio was updated on [May 24th, 2013](http://store.steampowered.com/news/10692/) to add a Retry option after completing a stage.**

This option is only available on the results screen shown directly after completing a stage.

If you are playing on Dreamcast or if you have already returned to the garage, your only option is to reload an old save or play through the story again. ([See wolf's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95046/181240))

[image: Option to replay a mission]

Comment: I don't whether this feature was included in the other HD ports, (PS3, Xbox 360, Vita, iOS, Android). If anyone knows feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score -2):

it doesnt have a replay feature

Comment: This was already covered by Wolf’s answer